# How can I disable the purple splash screen at boot?

Tags: boot, plymouth

How can I disable the purple "Ubuntu" splash screen that displays at boot before the login screen has loaded? I'd prefer to just see plain text scroll by.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Quote from `/usr/share/doc/plymouth/README.Debian` (from package `plymouth` version 0.8.2-2ubuntu2, which is the one installed on Ubuntu 10.04):

> There are two methods to disable the splash screen.  Both have the
> same effect.  Your boot will show such messages as are emitted by
> the starting services, and will still be able to prompt if needs be.
>
> 1. Remove all of the `plymouth-theme-*` packages from your system,
>    including the text ones.  Plymouth will remain installed to
>    permit boot-time prompts.
> 2. Remove `splash` from the kernel command-line.  You can do this
>    per-boot, or make it permanent by changing the
>    `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub`.

The second method also requires running `update-grub` as superuser, after editing that file.

Comment: Thanks, I never would have guessed it was called "plymouth". The second method worked great for me.

Comment: I've removed both quite and splash from my GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and I still get a blank, plain, purple screen while the kernel is loading.  Once the kernel is loaded and system services are starting then the splash goes away.

Comment: there is no /etc/default/grub on my system, I think because of the move to grub2, so where can I set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT when using grub2 ?

Comment: @Jay_silly_evarlast_Wren After editing `/etc/default/grub` you need to run `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes to the boot loader. See [the ubnutu grub help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2). `/etc/default/grub` exists on my ubuntu 12.10 installation.

Comment: "You can do this per-boot..." Do you know how? A quick google doesn't turn up anything useful.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat "per-boot" = edit the GRUB command-line by pressing `e` at the GRUB menu.

Answer (score 3):

## Temporarily disable splash

You can edit the boot entries in the menu from within GRUB to temporarily disable the splash screen.

Try the following: Select the entry, press the key to edit this entry (it should be <kbd>e</kbd>), go to the kernel/linux line and remove `quiet splash`, then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

Here are two screenshots from a VM to show you how it should look like:

[image]

## Permanently disable splash

The permanent equivalent was already quoted in [Riccardo Murri's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/5068):

> 2. Remove `splash` from the kernel command-line. You can do this per-boot, or make it permanent by changing the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub`.

... followed by `update-grub` as superuser.