# How to disable Plymouth?

Tags: apache2, plymouth

apache ask for passphrase redirects to plymouth even when I'm remoted in using SSH and away from console.

How can I disabled plymouth?

Update: I did learn that I can `sudo plymouth --quit` and that will shutdown plymouth. I would like to know the recommended way to disable plymouth on boot.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5065/how-can-i-disable-the-purple-splash-screen-at-boot

Comment: Just disabling the splash screen isn't enough. As long as plymouth is running it will respond to the plymouth --ping that apachectl uses.

Answer (score 3):

plymouth should be stopping on its own when the boot is finished.. on a GUI that is when kdm/xdm/gdm/lxdm start. On servers, that is when runlevel 2 is finished (ls /etc/rc2.d). If it is not stopped, this is likely a bug in the bootup, and should be reported with

```
apport-bug plymouth
```

Additional Resources:

- [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Answer (score 0):

The [How can I disable the purple splash screen at boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5065/how-can-i-disable-the-purple-splash-screen-at-boot) has been mentioned.

You could also edit the plymouth /1/ upstart /2/ config files and prevent the plymouth start-up. I think that the /etc/init/plymouth.conf will do the trick.

Links:

1. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth
2. http://upstart.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Just disabling the splash screen isn't enough. As long as plymouth is running it will respond to the plymouth --ping that apachectl uses.