# How can I disable the purple bootloader splash at boot?

Tags: 11.10, grub2, plymouth, bootloader, dmesg

[This question has been answered before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5065/how-can-i-disable-the-purple-splash-screen-at-boot), but neither of the methods in the accepted answer worked for me on 11.10.

First I tried editing in `/etc/default/grub`, and then running `sudo update-grub`.  But after that I still got a blank, plain, purple screen while the kernel is loading.  The screen has no boot options, and it obscures those dmesg that I want to see going in the terminal.

Next I tried removing the `plymouth-theme-*`, but that just broke my gnome-shell theme looks, and the purple screen still remains.

I have also tried configuring it with `startupmanager` package, but nothing seems to get rid of that darned purple splash.

here are the contents of my `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#    GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
sudo mv /etc/init/plymouth.conf /etc/init/plymouth.conf.disabled
```

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console` from `/etc/default/grub`.

Answer (score 1):

Grub loads its background color from `/lib/plymouth/themes/default.grub` (as seen in `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`).

I don't know the standard way of changing this color, but editing `/lib/plymouth/themes/default.grub` worked for me:

```
if background_color 0,0,0; then
    clear
fi
```

Then, from the commandline, type `sudo update-grub`