# How Can I Suppress "Load Fallback Graphics Devices" and "Plymouth Upstart Bridge" Messages During Ubuntu Server 14.04 Boot-Up?

Tags: boot, 14.04, server, upstart, plymouth

When booting Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS, I see messages such as:

`* Starting load fallback graphics devices [FAIL]`

and

`init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process terminated with status 1`

and

`init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning`

I'm running Linux version 3.13.0-32-generic in a VMware ESXi 5.1.0 virtual machine, and have no need for DRM, a graphical splash screen, kernel mode setting, Plymouth, Wayland or X-Windows.  A text console is fine by me.  I would remove Plymouth if I could, but there are too many dependencies in the way.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you install ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable the purple splash screen at boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5065/how-can-i-disable-the-purple-splash-screen-at-boot)

Comment: Plymouth should not have *that* many dependencies, and what do you need those dependencies for anyways ?

Comment: It's Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS with a minimal set of packages.  There is no desktop environment, no desktop manager, and no splash option on the kernel command line.

Comment: can you post the kernel line from grub ? Probably easiest to remove plymouth or disable the upstart script.

Comment: Also, presently there is no splash screen, only the annoying messages.

Comment: `Command line: root=/dev/disk/by-label/wgrd.root ro noplymouth initrd=/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic`

Comment: Try adding "quiet" after "noplymouth"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After obtaining additional information in the comments, adding "quiet" to the grub options resolved the problem.

On a server, use nano or vi(m) to edit /etc/default/grub

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Look for the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line

add quiet at the end of the option, in this case

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ro noplymouth quiet"
```

Next, update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

For additional information, See [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)

Comment: a downvote after many months after converting a comment to an answer, really ? Not that I need the reputation, but I have to say that is petty.