# GRUB_DEFAULT = _ is not working properly

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I did this setup due to Kernel upgrade bug:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT = 4
```

in `/etc/default/grub`

Than I executed

```
sudo setup-grub
```

However, it didn't work out. My desired version is 4.2.0-16-generic, because 4.2.0-18 and 4.2.0-17(which actually isn't listed) doesn't work. In the list, 4.2.0-16 is 4th.

When it didn't work, I tried this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT = "Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-16-generic"
```

and

```
sudo setup-grub
```

however, it still didn't work and opened a not-working version of kernel. Currently I can only access 4.2.0-16 manually through Advanced options for Ubuntu, but I want it to load automaticly. What solution would you reccomend me?

The `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` outputs:

```
ii  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-16-generic                          4.2.0-16.19                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-17-generic                          4.2.0-17.21                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-18-generic                          4.2.0-18.22                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                         4.2.0.18.20                                amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

as a last 4 outputs(only ones for Ubuntu 15.10 which contains Kernel 4.2.0).

Comment: Just a heads up, you confuse whatever `setup-grub` on your machine is with `update-grub`, but seem to have found that out by yourself already. To answer your comment: *"Why did Canonical provide us with a Kernel package that doesn't wrok and actually harms the computer?"* Don't assume such a thing, check that the kernel packages have been installed and initramfs images generated properly with all the modules that your machine needs. If the machine still does not properly boot up then disable the boot splash and note down the information or take a photo and report a bug.

Comment: I don't understand some stuff. What is boot splash? What is initramfs?

Comment: Disable boot splash temporarily http://askubuntu.com/q/5065/40581 – the command to update initramfs http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/update-initramfs.8.html (`sudo update-initramfs -u -k <version>` or `-k all` for all) – more detail about initramfs https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs

Comment: Aww... I don't like anything releated to that stuff... Anything releated to system. Do you know if this bug has been reported and if Ubuntu is fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I found the solution. I had to link a PPA to grub-customizer.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer`

Than I did:

`sudo apt-get update`

Next step is

`sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`

After that I open the grub-customizer through unity dash and select the  desired kernel from there and tada!:)

Comment: This does not solve the issue for systems that have no desktop env.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the IDs of the corresponding `submenu` and `menuentry` lines.

Note "*Advanced options for Ubuntu*" is a `submenu`, you need to use its ID.

Run `grep -E "^\\s*(menuentry|submenu) " /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

For example if the output is:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-7da0d9d5-45bc-40e4-b17e-18cff7a59b76' {
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-7da0d9d5-45bc-40e4-b17e-18cff7a59b76' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-140-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-140-generic-advanced-7da0d9d5-45bc-40e4-b17e-18cff7a59b76' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-140-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-140-generic-init-upstart-7da0d9d5-45bc-40e4-b17e-18cff7a59b76' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-140-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-140-generic-recovery-7da0d9d5-45bc-40e4-b17e-18cff7a59b76' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-101-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-101-generic-advanced-7da0d9d5-45bc-40e4-b17e-18cff7a59b76' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-101-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-101-generic-init-upstart-7da0d9d5-45bc-40e4-b17e-18cff7a59b76' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-101-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-101-generic-recovery-7da0d9d5-45bc-40e4-b17e-18cff7a59b76' {
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
```

The correct setting would be:

`GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-advanced-7da0d9d5-45bc-40e4-b17e-18cff7a59b76>gnulinux-4.4.0-101-generic-advanced-7da0d9d5-45bc-40e4-b17e-18cff7a59b76"`

Note you can also use a 0-based numbering, but do take the submenu entries into account:

`GRUB_DEFAULT="1>3"`

Don't forget to run `update-grub` at the end.

Answer (score 5):

1. Take a backup of your current grub.

   `sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak`
2. Now, open the file.

   `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
3. Open another terminal and type:

   `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep 4.2.0-16`

   You will see a line like this:

   > menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-16-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-18-generic-advanced-esx5367c-b4ug-19sd-v6j8-ty2hj01ui3kj' {..........
4. Copy this line & paste it:

**EDITED FROM:**

> GRUB_DEFAULT ="gnulinux-4.2.0-16-generic-advanced-2e2221b2-b6c7-4553-815f-67afdc924a98"

**EDITED TO:**

> GRUB_DEFAULT ="gnulinux-advanced-2e2221b2-b6c7-4553-815f-67afdc924a98>gnulinux-4.2.0-16-generic-advanced-2e2221b2-b6c7-4553-815f-67afdc924a98"

5. Save the file.
6. Now, type the command:

   `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Nop! Didn't work out... 
`gnulinux-4.2.0-16-generic-advanced-2e2221b2-b6c7-4553-815f-67afdc924a98` I pasted this line. I updated grub. But it still leads to not working version.
P.S. Why did Canonical provide us with a Kernel package that doesn't wrok and actually harms the computer?

Comment: I edited the line to above could you please see if it works now, there is text entered till >. Please review and see if it works now.

Comment: You mean it how?

The full lines:

`menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-16-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-16-generic-advanced-2e2221b2-b6c7-4553-815f-67afdc924a98' {
  echo 'Loading Linux 4.2.0-16-generic ...'
  linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic root=UUID=2e2221b2-b6c7-4553-815f-67afdc924a98 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
  initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic`

Comment: @AdriansNetlis - See the answer now, its been edited.

Comment: OK! Still nothing...:( Adding > and another copy of line didn't solve it. BTW, is it possible to access latest few boot logs? Maybe they can tell us something?

Comment: I just did it to test your question on my laptop and it works, though in the grub menu you might see the star beside the Advanced option, but it will boot your chosen kernel on timeout.

Comment: I will edit my answer with your UUID, just copy and paste it.

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/62156
Still doesn't work... It looks like this(the etc/default/grub)

Comment: @AdriansNetlis - You didn't paste it correctly. Check again carefully.

Comment: firstly - you added space before `=`. But even without it, it still didn't work. I copied your text pretty accurately(as accurately as Ctrl+C does, lol).

Comment: But the link that you shared has the wrong code, you can compare if you see.

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/62158 What about this one? And it doesn't work...

Comment: Yes thats correct. But I did the same thing and its working for me. :'(

Comment: Maybe your kernels are not broken? So if the syntax of it have mistake, it sets it to use 0 instead of what is located there, I guess. And for you 0 works, but not for me. However, I tried all the numbers from 0 to 4 and none worked...

Comment: Yes thats the only difference, mine aren't broken.

Comment: But why did some people receive broken 4.2.0-17 and 4.2.0-18, but others did not? Wait a minute - did I actually try the 4.2.0-18, lol? I had set it to 4 before latest updated. I forgot to `sudo update-grub` when I think so now... Maybe I must try running 18?

Comment: Hmm Maybe, please share your results

Answer (score 0):

Little bash function to list all Ubuntu kernels suitable for inserting into
`GRUB_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`

```
 MENUID=$( grep -E "^\\s*(submenu) " /boot/grub/grub.cfg  | grep -oP "gnuli.*(?=')"    )
grep '(?<=menuentry_id_option ).gnuli\S+' /boot/grub/grub.cfg  -Po | \
    sed "s@'@@g" |grep -vE 'recovery|simple|gnulinux-advanced' | sed "s@^@GRUB_DEFAULT=\"${MENUID}>@; s@\$@\"@"
```

Output:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-advanced-20dfee37-ad84-49b2-8c69-a54699da855d>gnulinux-6.6.10-usb2-advanced-20dfee37-ad84-49b2-8c69-a54699da855d"
GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-advanced-20dfee37-ad84-49b2-8c69-a54699da855d>gnulinux-5.15.0-35-generic-advanced-20dfee37-ad84-49b2-8c69-a54699da855d"
```

Then simply pick one and paste into  `/etc/default/grub` & run `update-grub` & reboot.