# How to get past the purple screen of death with multiple GPUs using Nvidia drivers?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 17.10

I have an Ubuntu 17.10 installation and I would like to connect two Nvidia GTX 1070 graphic cards and use the Nvidia official driver instead of the Nouveau drivers.

I have tested the following versions of the official drivers:

```
390.25
387.34
384.111
```

With each one I have no problems to boot up using a single graphics card, but with two I get stuck on the purple screen of death.

I tried to [disable the purple screen](https://askubuntu.com/a/5068/64420) so that I can diagnose the error, but I even failed at that.

I feel pretty much stuck in here, so any hints whatsoever are warmly welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer describes what worked for me.

It turns out that the problem was maybe caused by me using a HDMI connected TV instead of a normal VGA monitor as a primary screen.

I changed the settings in BIOS to use VGA as primary output and connected the cable directly to the motherboard instead of the graphics card. Then I re-installed the system and everything is working now.