# Viewing tail -f ---disable-inotify /var/log/syslog during bootup, GDM, GNOME

Tags: gnome, process, log, gdm

During bootup, I was able to disable splash screen (using [How can I disable the purple splash screen at boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5065/how-can-i-disable-the-purple-splash-screen-at-boot) instructions) so that I can see the scrolling information (controlled by init.d) of what is being loaded and if they were successful. However, once GRUB is logged as a successful startup, the GDM (I think) takes over and I do not see anything.  Is there a way to have everything parsed onscreen from GRUB to GDM (check did that I see from GRUB to run level 3) to a successful Gnome GUI (run level 5) Desktop Environment?

For those that think I am asking to disable splash my /etc/default/grub file:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
# GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_BACKGROUND=/home/[my username]/Pictures/black2.jpg

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1920x1080

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

After doing some digging and research, I am looking to see if there is a process or method that allows me to view a window or screen while my system boots; GDM starts; I log-in [different log]; GDM ends; GNOME starts, lastly, GNOME is up and running so that I can view the realtime output of

```
sudo tail -f ---disable-inotify /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable the purple splash screen at boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5065/how-can-i-disable-the-purple-splash-screen-at-boot)

Comment: I have disabled the splash screen (purple splash screen).  I want to see what is being loaded after that.