# How to disable the bootsplash?

Tags: boot, 20.04, plymouth

While I was using Ubuntu 18.04 I was so annoyed with the purple bootsplash and used a png logo of HP as my bootsplash. But yesterday, I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and now I realized that the new Ubuntu Studios bootsplash is Amazing! but the problem is that I don't remember how did I set the Hp logo as bootsplash as I can't find it in my Plymouth settings and both boot splashes are merging. So I want to disable the HP logo bootsplash. How can I do it?

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but you might have put the image file in /boot/grub.  I think grub takes the first image it finds there and uses it for a splash image.  You can also edit your /etc/default/grub file and change the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT parameter.  Please see this question from several years ago: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5065/how-can-i-disable-the-purple-splash-screen-at-boot.

Comment: @StephenDaddona looks like it doesn't help there is no such file in my directory

Comment: You might need to do sudo su and then look for /etc/default/grub.  Don't forget to run update-grub after you make your changes.

Comment: @StephenDaddona Bruh! now I finally found the final and made the changes. But, I have a question? If I used plymouth theme now . Will it run. Or I have to change the setting again. Thanks, Brother.

Comment: Alas, I know nothing of plymouth (or themes either).  My hardware was not supported after Ubuntu 14.04 (video card no longer supported in the kernel) so I was never able to upgrade Ubuntu after that.  I can only surmise, but I expect that a theme that worked before will continue to work.

Comment: Also, you are saving a backup copy of each file that you change, correct?  That is always a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this question as I fixed the situation with the help of a very humble guy named @StephenDaddona. Read comments on the first post for the fix.
Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Harsh Upadhyay for the kind words.  I'm glad I was able to help.  I don't know much, but sometimes a little bit is all it takes.